# I am not able to figure this code what it actually means

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I don’t know how this code is working and it’s jQuery or JavaScript.

Here in this code, what does this `` ` `` symbol signify? If I am replacing it with `'` then it’s not giving me output.

The other problem is count is declared above and its now id so how can we use
`${count}` how it is getting value, what I have studied 
`var myElement = document.getElementById("id");` and `var myElement = $("#id");` are same but it works on id and count here is const not id.

```
const count = counter[member.assigned];

trHTML += `<tr><td rowspan=${count}>${member.assigned}</td><td>${member.assigned}</td></tr>`;
```

Comment: The back tick is used for string interpolation and replaces the more traditional `let myvar = variable + "string";`

Comment: See [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9549780/4642212) and the documentation on MDN about [expressions and operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are javascript [template string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).  They allow expressions to be easily inserted into strings.

```js
const foo = 'foofoo';
const bar = 'barbar';

console.log(`What is a ${foo} or ${bar}?`); // values inserted into string
```